# Managing mysql databases

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I modeled a database using MySQL Workbench. On my live site I have multiple instances of this database. Same structure, different content. Naming convention is something like db_user1, db_user2, etc.

If I make changes to the structure, how can I easily push those to the different databases?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer: http://liquibase.org/

Supports database versioning, automatic sync, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually. 
or may be you can create procedures for it. 
e.g. you have rename the table name then you need to create a procedure and call them to change the name in other database also.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench has a functcion "Synchronize with any source" (see database menu). You can invoke this function once for each target db.